# Lookup formula to find last instance of value not working

Tags: lookup, google-sheets-formula

Suppose Cell A1 = John
Column B: [John, Terry, Mike, Dana, John, Moe]
Column C: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

My attempt

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B$6=$A$1),$C$1:$C$6)
```

Expected result: 5
Actual result: "N/A": Did not find value 2 in vlookup

Comment: Your title is confusing.  Your formula works fine here in Excel.  It does not work in Sheets.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I don't have access to an Excel doc right now so am using Google Sheets in lieu. Why is not working on Sheets and what would be the alternative to fulfill my intended goal?

Comment: Have you tried entering it as an array formula in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative in Sheets, assuming you have sequential numbers in column C:

```
=ArrayFormula(max((A1=B1:B6)*C1:C6))
```

If Column C is not sequential, or numeric, then:

```
ArrayFormula(index(C1:C6,(max((A1=B1:B6)*ROW(C1:C6)))))
```

The above formulas will also work in EXCEL (by using CSE instead of ArrayFormula) but the LOOKUP method, in Excel, is simpler.

Comment: What about in the case that it's not sequential? I know that I can get around this by simply sorting that column sequentially but in the context of this problem, I have to assume it will not be sequential and cannot change the order, i.e. get the last/most recent value of that instance

Answer (score 0):

Your formula works, but **you have to enter it as array formula!**

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B$6=$A$1),$C$1:$C$6))
```

**Notes:**

1. This formula will return *#N/A* if the $A$1 value is not found. So wrap in *IFERROR()* if necessary.
2. Depending on the usage *COUNTA()* or *COUNTA()+INDEX()* might to the job while being shorter/not requiring ArrayFormula.